# Cannot set property 'stepup' of undefined UVCHARTS

Tags: javascript

El error que he puesto en el título es el que me sale al hacer el código del tutorial de UvCharts:

```
 var chart = uv.chart ('Bar', graphdef);

var graphdef = {
    categories : ['uvCharts', 'matisse', 'bot-bot', 'SocialByWay'],
    dataset : {
        'uvCharts' : [
            { name : '2009', value : 32 },
            { name : '2010', value : 60 },
            { name : '2011', value : 97 },
            { name : '2012', value : 560 },
            { name : '2013', value : 999 }
        ],

        'matisse' : [
            { name : '2009', value : 58 },
            { name : '2010', value : 75 },
            { name : '2011', value : 90 },
            { name : '2012', value : 740 },
            { name : '2013', value : 890 }      
        ],

        'bot-bot' : [
            { name : '2009', value : 43 },
            { name : '2010', value : 88 },
            { name : '2011', value : 100 },
            { name : '2012', value : 420 },
            { name : '2013', value : 769 }  
        ],

        'SocialByWay' : [
            { name : '2009', value : 88 },
            { name : '2010', value : 120 },
            { name : '2011', value : 157 },
            { name : '2012', value : 450 },
            { name : '2013', value : 1024 } 
        ],

        'WaveMaker' : [
            { name : '2009', value : 32 },
            { name : '2010', value : 60 },
            { name : '2011', value : 97 },
            { name : '2012', value : 560 },
            { name : '2013', value : 999 }  
        ]
    }
}
```

Y en el html tengo importado tando d3.js como uvcharts y el div:

```
<div id="uv-div">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la documentación de uvCharts están mal dichos enlaces , si alguien le sirve..

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uvCharts/1.1.5/uvcharts.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

revisa si es por que no has definido WaveMaker en categories

agrégalo en categories

```
categories : ['uvCharts', 'matisse', 'bot-bot', 'SocialByWay','WaveMaker'],
```

Comment: Sigue lanzando el mismo error aún poniendolo así